# UICollectionView segue from Sign-up showing a black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

I have a social app that requires login/sign-up. This is done with the ParseUI library that present a custom window for user validation.

When a user signs up, I want to display a CollectionView where users choose some preferences (each as a cell) and proceed to the app.

In the Sign-Up View Controller I have this:

```
- (void)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController didSignUpUser:(PFUser *)user { 

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ChooseLeagueCollectionViewController *clvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChooseLeagueViewController"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    [self presentViewController:clvc animated:NO completion:NULL];
    }
```

Do I need to alloc and init a flowLayout object even though it is already present in my storyboard?

In my storyboard I have a CollectionViewController containing one cell linked to a subclass of UICollectionViewCell with an ImageView and a Label. This storyboard file has as custom class 'ChooseLeagueViewController' which is a subclass of CollectionViewController, and is also data source and delegate.

In the .h file I have:

```
@interface ChooseLeagueCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
```

In the .m file I implement all the required methods that the datasource and delegate protocols require. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I populate the cell (subclass of CollectionviewCell), change the label text and text color, the image, and than return it.

Also I am not sure why I am asked to register my cell like below, even though my cell has a reusable identifier in the storyboard.

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[LeagueCollectionViewCell class]forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"leagueCell"];
```

Anyway when I run the app, after signing up, i am brought to a completly black screen but the battery. the app does not crash and all the 'data source' methods are called correctly.

I think that there is something wrong in the way I am trying to show this View.

Any guess on how I could improve my segue or what the mistake is?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply alloc,init will give you blank controller with no view associated with it. You have to initialise it through storyboard like this, then you will not have to provide any custom init/alloc,

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ChooseLeagueCollectionViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:NULL];

You specify viewController identifier in storyboard by selecting your viewController and in identity Inspector in storyboard id. :)